# TINYMCE: Add class to custom dialog box input/select field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-5

How do we add a specific **class** to one or more input fields in [TINYMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/) (Version: 5.9.2) custom dialog box?

If it is not possible, **can we add any data-attribute**?

```
var addLinkDialogConfig =  {
    title: 'Add Link',
    body: {
        type: 'panel',
        items: [
           {
                type: 'input',
                name: 'link_id',
                label: 'Enter ID',
            },
            {
                type: 'selectbox',
                name: 'link_type',
                label: 'Select Type',
                items: [
                    { text: 'Value 1', value: 'val1' },
                    { text: 'Value 2', value: 'val2' },
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    buttons: [
        {
            type: 'submit',
            name: 'submitButton',
            text: 'Add',
            primary: true
        }
    ],
    onSubmit: function (api) {
        console.log(api);
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This link *may* help, best https://community.plone.org/t/preferred-method-to-add-a-class-to-an-anchor-tag-a-in-tinymce-solved/11258/3

Comment: Hi, @dalelandry I read the conversation, and it seems the solution for adding custom class and styling to content of tinymce instead of adding class to an input/select field of custom dialog box inside TINYMCE! So my concern is, *I want to add a class to field* (`<select class="myclass"></select>`) or any other html attribute if possible, so that I can add an event through js/jquery to that element! Thanks for the help! :)